# How to send body data from swagger using Node.js/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

Here is my swagger config:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/addData:
 *    post:
 *     consumes:
 *       - text/html
 *     produces:
 *       - text/html
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: author
 *         in: body
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: string
 *       - name: email
 *         in: body
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: string
 *       - name: text
 *         in: body
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: string
 *     tags:
 *       - Create single message
 *     description: Creates single message
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *    description: You have created new message
 */
```

And I have the next backend code:

```
app.post('/api/addData', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // {}
})
```

Everything seems ok, but when I am trying to execute request with Swagger UI, I'm getting an empty object in my console.
The question is, how to config swagger so that he can send data from my body?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem with the following code:

```
/**
* @swagger
*  /api/addData:
*    post:
*      summary: Creates a new message.
*      consumes:
*        - application/json
*      tags:
*        - Create a new message
*      parameters:
*        - in: body
*          name: user
*          description: The user to create.
*          schema:
*            type: object
*            required:
*              - name
*              - email
*              - text
*            properties:
*              name:
*                type: string
*              email:
*                type: string
*              text:
*                type: string
*      responses:
*        201:
*          description: New message created!
*/
```